# How to save the selected item from a inputlistitem to a json model

Tags: sapui5

I want to save the selected list item from the `InputListItem` in a JSON Model...which tag is used and if function is used then how does one proceed ?

```
<InputListItem label="Country" >
    <Select >
        <core:Item key="GR" text="Greece" />
        <core:Item key="MX" text="Mexico"/>
        <core:Item key="NO" text="Norway"/>
        <core:Item key="NZ" text="New Zealand"/>
        <core:Item key="NL" text="Netherlands"/>
    </Select>
</InputListItem>
```

Comment: Check this as well: i feel quite similar to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54476090/what-is-the-standard-way-to-get-values-from-select-tag-in-sapui5-if-is-presen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InputListItem` is just a wrapper for an Input control so you need to look at the documentation for this is use case (`<Select>` tag) in the [sap.m.Select control](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Select/overview).

You will probably need to bind the `selectedKey` property to your model:

```
<InputListItem label="Country" >
    <Select selectedKey="{model>/property}">
        <core:Item key="GR" text="Greece" />
        <!-- ... -->
    </Select>
</InputListItem>
```

Where `model>/property` refers to the model and property you wish to bind this result to.

---

**Edit**: If you want the text, the easiest way to do it is to set the key to be the text itself.

e.g.

```
<core:Item key="Greece" text="Greece" />
```

The other alternative is to add a listener on the change event and manually add the text of the selected item to the model. But this is more involved and the selected method depends on what you are trying to develop.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The above way displays the key only and not the actual data.How can i access the text in the list.  For ex. I want to send the text "Greece" instead of the key " GR"

Comment: Edited the answer to do what you need. It really depends on what you are trying to achieve.